# Detecting use after free() on windows. (dangling pointers)

Tags: c++, c, security, testing

I'm trying to detect "Use after free()"  bugs,  otherwise known as "Dangling pointers".  I know Valgrind can be used to detect "Use after free"  bugs on the *nix platform,  but what about windows?  What if I don't have the source?  Is there a better program than Valgrind for detecting all dangling pointers in a program?   A free and open source would be preferred ,  but I'll use a commercial solution if it will get the job done.

Comment: C++ is one of the tags. I never heard that "C++" programmers use `free`.

Comment: You can still get a dangling pointer with delete.   But "use after free()" is a more common term than "Dangling pointer".

Comment: @The Rook:  There must be different communities around.  I'd say "dangling pointer" and expect people to understand.  I wouldn't say "use after free()".

Comment: I use free a lot if I want to use realloc in C++

Comment: If you don't have the source, then you cannot fix the problem, and then this is no longer a programming related question.

Comment: @Clifford Breaking software is a programming problem and writing exploit code is still software development :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSVC debug memory allocator already does this.  When you get 0xfeeefeee from a pointer dereference you've dangled.  With some luck that will bomb the program.

Comment: Thats cool, but I'm attempting to track down all possible cases of this bug as efficiently as possible.  Stepping though a large program line by line is time consuming, although variable break points would help.

Comment: But what happens if the memory containing 0xfeeefeee gets re-used for a new object? Then this method of detection does not work.

Comment: @jmatthias: bad use of a dangling pointer into recycled memory is called a "temporal" memory error.   Our tool, SafetyCheck, will catch this.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety

Answer (score 5):

You can use `gflags.exe` and the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/Debugging/default.mspx) to enable heap checking in a process:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265885.aspx

It's been a while since I've used this, and I honestly can't remember how well it interacts with the C runtime heap as opposed to the Windows heap manager (to ensure that each `malloc()`/`free()`/`new`/`delete` call is separately checked).

Free, but not open source.

Comment: "Page Heap" option in gflags.exe changes the way heap is working. Since malloc/free/new/delete just call heap API, "Page Heap" is a great way to detect majority of memory violation.

The actual functionality is embedded in Windows, gflags.exe just changes something in the registry.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite as good as Valgrind, but Microsoft's [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en) performs a similar function for Windows. It also will let you simulate error conditions for most of the API to tell you if things are going to blow up in your most important client's face :)

Answer (score 2):

Years ago I used [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) for this purpose. It's been around for a long time and was quite good when I used it.

Comment: I have used purify,  it only seems to detect bugs after the program has crashed.  I'm looking for new ways to crash the application :)

Comment: I've used Purify, and it definitely was able to catch all sorts of memory problems like dangling pointer, double delete, array bounds, memory leak (many false positives on the system I worked on). Obviously sometimes the program will crash too. On any sort of runtime checker you *have* to execute the broken code or it won't be able to detect it. If you're looking for a static checker that's a different question entirely.

Comment: Trivia: Purify was, at a certain extent, the cause of the Debian SSH bug. :P

Comment: @Matteo your right,  it was also humans not understanding a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

See CheckPointer, our [Memory Safety Checker for C](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety).  Does require you have the source code, but does run on Wndows.

Answer (score 0):

NuMega BoundsChecker used to catch this stuff. Not sure if they're still in business though...

Comment: They check for both conditions, and then some more.

Answer (score 0):

[DieHard](http://www.hoard.org/) is another alternative worth looking at.  It's on the HOARDE website, which unfortunately seems to use frames, so you'll need to look in the left-hand navigation to find DieHard.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the Windows debug heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8h19c37%28VS.80%29.aspx). It's not open source, but works.

Answer (score 0):

After the free(), set the pointer value to 0 and wait for the fireworks?